# Ethernet connection gets self-assigned IP when Wi-Fi turned on?

Tags: wifi, internet, ethernet

I've been having this issue consistently since upgrading my MacBook Pro (late 2018) to Catalina where if I have Wi-fi turned off, my ethernet cable plugged in, and I restart my machine; upon restarting I will have an internet connection. Everything is fine.

Yet if I disconnect my ethernet cable (because I need to change locations) and turn on my Wi-fi, whenever I plug my ethernet cable back in later I always get following error:

> USB 10/100/1000 LAN has a self-assigned IP address and will not be able to connect to the Internet.

If I restart (as described above), everything works fine. This is really annoying. I use to be able to plug in an ethernet cable and get an internet connection in previous macOS versions. How can I correct this?

Comment: This is unclear: "Yet if I turn on disconnect my ethernet cable...."

Comment: @IconDaemon Updated to be a bit clearer